# Is it possible to automate Excel without having it installed?

Tags: c#, excel, windows-8, windows-store-apps, openoffice-calc

I don't have Excel installed; don't have a license for it, and don't want to pay the $$$. I use Open Office.

However, I need to automate xls files. Is it possible to programmatically convert these to Open Office spreadsheet files (Calc), automate them, then convert them back to xls (without having Excel installed)?

If so, how?

What I want to do is:
1) Programmatically open, if necessary, an existing xls file (no GUI representation, just in memory)
2) Convert the xls file to Open Office file type
3) Programmatically change the contents of the spreadsheet
4) Save back to xls file type so that users with Excel can open it

Or possibly I can leave Open Office out of the loop altogether (officially/programmatically, just using it to check my results).

And, BTW, this in a Windows 8/Store app (that will run on a tablet or desktop).

Comment: xls or xlsx? Makes a big difference.

Comment: xls; that is to say: xls

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will be better off handling the task programatically. Take a look at [OpenXML SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124) and [NPOI](http://npoi.codeplex.com/) - the Apache POI port to .NET. They'll run on your desktop/laptop, however I'm not sure, whether they'll run flawlessly on your mobile devices, that you target with your app.